# What kind of roses are these?

Tags: identification, flowers, roses

I would be able to get a closer picture, if needed.
[image]

Comment: Often your best bet is to snoop around underneath and see if there's a tag, or just ask the owner if they know or have any documentation, or any idea how long it's been there (which can eliminate some newer cultivars if it's a long time.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal, they do not have tags and their owners do not know the details. They have been there for at least twenty years.

Answer (score 9):

It's next to impossible to give a 100% definite ID I'm afraid - it might help if you could provide a close up of a fully open flower and a bud that's showing colour but nowhere near open to decide whether its an HT or floribunda rose, but on current showing, it would appear to be a floribunda, possibly something like 'Mardi Gras' but there are literally thousands of rose varieties, some with only minor differences. Many flowers start out as one shade of a colour and change over a few days to a darker or lighter shade. You haven't mentioned fragrance, is there a fragrance? How many separate plants are in the picture? Height and spread can be another determinant of variety.

Comment: Thank you! I am working on getting closer pictures of them and other details you mentioned. They grow up to 1.5 meters tall.